# How to assign random colors to D3 bar chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a D3 bar chart as per the mock-up below:

[image: Bar Chart]

How do I make the bars to have random colors?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/MjFgK/)

Code:

```
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

d3 has 4 built in color palettes.

Here's the [**`link`**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#category10) for the built in color palettes.

[**`This`**](https://www.dashingd3js.com/d3js-scales) tutorial is good on using specific colors for specific element.

Another [**`tutorial`**](http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2011/08/11/d3-scales-and-color/) by Jerome Cukier.

And the official [**`site`**](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Colors) for d3 colors.

[**`Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/MjFgK/4/) - Note: In the fiddle I've passed the colors by adding colors in the data.

It can even be done by passing the colors from a different variables.

Hope this helps.

Comment: how do I add the grey scale that shows full scale of Y-axis in the background of the bars?

Comment: I'm not clear. You wanted to add horizontal grid lines?

Comment: No, if you consider a single bar in the snapshot in the question, it has a grey scale parallel to Y-axis that resembles 100%. How do I add that to my chart?

Comment: Can you open a new post for that? Please do it with a fiddle because I'm not expert in what you asked now but i'll give it a try. Other peoples may also help you.

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823226/get-striped-grey-background-resembling-100-to-the-barchart

Answer (score 7):

```
colors = d3.scale.category20()

rects = svg.selectAll('rect')
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("class","rect")
                .....#other attributes
                .attr("fill",function(d,i){return colors(i)})
```

Answer (score 5):

this is old now, but this is a pretty good approach if you need N number of random colors

http://bl.ocks.org/jdarling/06019d16cb5fd6795edf