# How to get striped grey background resembling 100% to the barchart?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821304/how-to-assign-random-colors-to-d3-bar-chart). 
How do I get the striped grey scale in the background which represents 100% and is parallel to Y-axis?
[image]

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/MjFgK/7/)

Code:

```
var data = [
    {
        "age": "Under 18",
        "value": "582.13",
        "color": "#B3DA29"
    },
    {
        "age": "18 - 22",
        "value": "583.98",
        "color": "#78C0F2"
    },
    {
        "age": "23 - 34",
        "value": "603.00",
        "color": "#9B58B5"
    },
    {
        "age": "35 - 60",
        "value": "607.70",
        "color": "#E54C3C"
    },
    {
        "age": "60 - Above",
        "value": "610.00",
        "color": "#F2519D"
    }
];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.ticks(10, "%");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.age; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")   
.attr("class", "tooltip")               
.style("opacity", 0);

svg.selectAll(".bar")
.data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "bar")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.age); })
.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
.attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
.style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; })
.attr("rx", 10)
.attr("ry", 10)
.on("mouseover", function(d) {      
    tooltip.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", .9);      
    tooltip.html("Count: " + d.value)  
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
})                  
.on("mouseout", function(d) {       
    tooltip.transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0);   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it works.

Updated the [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/MjFgK/8/).

```
svg.selectAll(".backgound-bar")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("class", "background-bar")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.age); })
.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(800); })
.attr("height", height)
.style("fill", "#ddd")
.attr("rx", 10)
.attr("ry", 10)
```

Created a `svg` element with the class `background-bar`.

And the `x` and `y` remains the same as you've defined prior.

But the height of the bars are given to the `height` variable defined.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How do I set the `height` to be the sum of all `values` in `data[]` ?

Comment: Also the `border-radius` for the grey bar isnt working.

Comment: It's easy. Store the sum to a variable using this function. `d3.sum(data, function(d) { return d.value; })`. And pass that variable to the height of the bars. And the border radius is actually working. Just increase the top margin and you'll see the border radius.

Comment: I increased the `top-margin` and got it working. But the grey bar is covering up the labels on X-axis. http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/MjFgK/10/

Comment: Reason the bar is like that because the height of the is 5 to 6 times greater than the height of each bar. I suggest you to take give a fixed value or take the `max` value and add some value to it.[**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/MjFgK/11/).

Comment: In this [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/MjFgK/12/) the background bar height is set by the height defined not by the sum.

Comment: I prefer this fiddle that you shared: http://jsfiddle.net/MjFgK/11/ How do I scale it down to look decent on a webpage?

Comment: You can't make it decent taking the sum. You need to fix the value instead of taking sum. In this [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/MjFgK/12/) I've set the value of the background bar myself. I'd suggest you to go by this.

Comment: Here is one follow-up question if you would like to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824412/how-to-rotate-x-axis-labels-onto-the-bar-in-bar-chart

Comment: I tried changing the value of first bar and this is what happened: http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/MjFgK/21/ How do I fix this?

Comment: Just changed the height to the `svg` element height. [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/MjFgK/23/)

Comment: Another follow-up question if you would like to answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826222/unable-to-get-drop-shadow-on-the-bars

Comment: Regarding the height of the grey bar, I believe this would be a better solution: http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/MjFgK/50/ I set `.attr("y", 0).attr("height", height)` to the grey bar.

Comment: Even that's a good idea. Setting the height variable as the max height of the bar. And even the bar chart looks very great. Can i know how did you add that stiped backgroud?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47878/discussion-between-rahul-desai-and-unknown-user)