# How to rotate X-axis labels onto the bar in bar chart?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I need to align x-axis labels as shown in the snapshot below:

[image]

I tried:

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(-90)" 
})
```

But it rotated the whole axis/scale.

How do I fix this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/MjFgK/13/)

**EDIT:**
I updated my code:

```
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis)
.selectAll("text")  
.style("text-anchor", "end")
.attr("dx", "0em")
.attr("dy", "0em")
.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(-90)" 
});
```

Now the labels are rotated to -90 degrees. How do I get it onto the bars?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/MjFgK/16/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that good in using `translate`. But this [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/MjFgK/17/) just works fine.

Reason why the whole axis/scale got rotated is because when the text being created with `x` and `y` position, the origin point of it becomes `(0,0)`.

So to rotate your text labels you need to position those text using `translate` instead of `x and y`.

In the [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/MjFgK/17/) I've added the below code at the bottom where it text labels are being rotated.

If you wanted to rotate it more. You can just change the degree of rotation.

```
svg.selectAll(".text")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("text")
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + (35 + x(d.age)) + ", 250)" + "rotate(-90)"
})
.text(function(d) { return d.age; })
```

Hope this helps for you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to rotate only text, and then translate it properly. See the updated fiddle:

```
svg.selectAll('.tick')
.select('text')
.attr('transform', 'rotate(-90) translate(50, -12)');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MjFgK/18/

Comment: That was very short. Great! +1 :)