# Unable to get drop-shadow on the bars

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am working on a bar chart and I need to get the chart to look like this:

[image]

Here is what I tried:

```
.attr("id", "drop-shadow")
.attr("height", "130%");
```

but it did not work.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/MjFgK/26/)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/MjFgK/29/).

Chart looks like that same as the image.

But i didn't do it adding a drop shadow.

Added `ellipse` before the bar being created and that gives the same effect as above.

```
svg.selectAll(".ellipse")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("ellipse")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.age) + 30; })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(0); })
.attr("rx", 35)
.attr("ry", 5)
.style("fill", function(d) { return d.color2; })
```

This is very simple. You need to create a ellipse before the bar is created.

When we position the ellipse it acts like a drop shadow.

Sorry that i don't have time to get the contrasting colors of the bar. But you can amend it of course.

If you'd like to do it with a drop shadow.

Here's a [**`link`**](http://bl.ocks.org/cpbotha/5200394) that requires a javascript library for the drop shadow of the svg elements.

Hope this helps.